Am I implementing my perceptron with backpropagation correctly?
I'm learning about perceptrons in class and how to use backpropagation to train the model. I'm currently having trouble with my implementation because it's only providing me a 50% accuracy rate with the data I'm given, while the majority of others in my class is getting a 90% rate. Is there something I'm overlooking in my implementation? This is what I have so far from the sources I've looked at.
class Perceptron():
    def __init__(self, num_features):
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.weights = np.random.rand(num_features) * 0.1 # This makes an array filled w/ zeros with the shape of num_features
        self.bias = 0.0
        
    def forward(self, x):
        linear = np.dot(x, self.weights) + self.bias
        print(linear)
        predictions = np.where(linear > 0, 1, 0)
        return predictions
        
    def backward(self, x, y, predictions):
        errors = y - predictions
        self.weights += self.learning_rate * np.dot(x.T, errors)
        self.bias += self.learning_rate * np.sum(errors)
        return errors
        
    def train(self, x, y, epochs, learning_rate = 0.01):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        for e in range(epochs):
            for i in range(y.shape[0]):
                x_i, y_i = x[i], y[i]
                prediction = self.forward(x_i)
                self.backward(x_i, y_i, prediction)
                
    def evaluate(self, x, y):
        predictions = self.forward(x)
        accuracy = np.mean(predictions == y)
        return accuracy

So far, I've tried different learning rates and asking others in my class, which to be quite honest, hasn't really changed the outcome of my implementation. I'm expecting a ~90% accuracy rate, but I'm only getting a 50% accuracy rate.
Here is some sample data:
0.77    -1.14   0
-0.33   1.44    0
0.91    -3.07   0
-0.37   -1.91   0
-1.84   -1.13   0
-1.50   0.34    0
-0.63   -1.53   0
-1.08   -1.23   0
0.39    -1.99   0
-1.26   -2.90   0
-5.27   -0.78   0
-0.49   -2.74   0
1.48    -3.74   0
-1.64   -1.96   0
0.45    0.36    0
-1.48   -1.17   0
-2.94   -4.47   0
-2.19   -1.48   0
0.02    -0.02   0
-2.24   -2.12   0
-3.17   -3.69   0
-4.09   1.03    0
-2.41   -2.31   0
-3.45   -0.61   0
-3.96   -2.00   0
-2.95   -1.16   0
-2.42   -3.35   0
-1.74   -1.10   0
-1.61   -1.28   0
-2.59   -2.21   0
-2.64   -2.20   0
-2.84   -4.12   0
-1.45   -2.26   0
-3.98   -1.05   0
-2.97   -1.63   0
-0.68   -1.52   0
-0.10   -3.43   0
-1.14   -2.66   0
-2.92   -2.51   0
-2.14   -1.62   0
-3.33   -0.44   0
-1.05   -3.85   0
0.38    0.95    0
-0.05   -1.95   0
-3.20   -0.22   0
-2.26   0.01    0
-1.41   -0.33   0
-1.20   -0.71   0
-1.69   0.80    0
-1.52   -1.14   0
3.88    0.65    1
0.73    2.97    1
0.83    3.94    1
1.59    1.25    1
3.92    3.48    1
3.87    2.91    1
1.14    3.91    1
1.73    2.80    1
2.95    1.84    1
2.61    2.92    1
2.38    0.90    1
2.30    3.33    1
1.31    1.85    1
1.56    3.85    1
2.67    2.41    1
1.23    2.54    1
1.33    2.03    1
1.36    2.68    1
2.58    1.79    1
2.40    0.91    1
0.51    2.44    1
2.17    2.64    1
4.38    2.94    1
1.09    3.12    1
0.68    1.54    1
1.93    3.71    1
1.26    1.17    1
1.90    1.34    1
3.13    0.92    1
0.85    1.56    1
1.50    3.93    1
2.95    2.09    1
0.77    2.84    1
1.00    0.46    1
3.19    2.32    1
2.92    2.32    1
2.86    1.35    1
0.97    2.68    1
1.20    1.31    1
1.54    2.02    1
1.65    0.63    1
1.36    -0.22   1
2.63    0.40    1
0.90    2.05    1
1.26    3.54    1
0.71    2.27    1
1.96    0.83    1
2.52    1.83    1
2.77    2.82    1
4.16    3.34    1

Before using the perceptron model, this code is first randomized and then split into 2 parts: 2/3 of the original data into training and the other 1/3 into testing. After that, z-score standardization is performed the first 2 features of the training and testing datasets.
This is how I'm using the class:
perceptron = Perceptron(num_features = 2)
perceptron.train(combined_x_train[:, :2], combined_x_train[:, 2], epochs = 5, learning_rate=0.1)
accuracy = perceptron.evaluate(x_train, y_train)
print(f'Final Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%')


Hey, how do you use this class ? which date are you giving as a input ?

I went ahead and added some sample data, along with some code snippets on how I used the Perceptron class.

did you use StandardScaler() before using your code ?

I'm not able to use StandardScaler() for this assignment, since the professor is limiting us to only built-in python modules, Matplotlib, and numpy

does it answer your question ?

It does, I just forgot to mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot!

Here is my implementation :
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Sample data provided
data = np.array([
    [0.77, -1.14, 0], [-0.33, 1.44, 0], [0.91, -3.07, 0], [-0.37, -1.91, 0],
    [-1.84, -1.13, 0], [-1.50, 0.34, 0], [-0.63, -1.53, 0], [-1.08, -1.23, 0],
    [0.39, -1.99, 0], [-1.26, -2.90, 0], [-5.27, -0.78, 0], [-0.49, -2.74, 0],
    [1.48, -3.74, 0], [-1.64, -1.96, 0], [0.45, 0.36, 0], [-1.48, -1.17, 0],
    [-2.94, -4.47, 0], [-2.19, -1.48, 0], [0.02, -0.02, 0], [-2.24, -2.12, 0],
    [-3.17, -3.69, 0], [-4.09, 1.03, 0], [-2.41, -2.31, 0], [-3.45, -0.61, 0],
    [-3.96, -2.00, 0], [-2.95, -1.16, 0], [-2.42, -3.35, 0], [-1.74, -1.10, 0],
    [-1.61, -1.28, 0], [-2.59, -2.21, 0], [-2.64, -2.20, 0], [-2.84, -4.12, 0],
    [-1.45, -2.26, 0], [-3.98, -1.05, 0], [-2.97, -1.63, 0], [-0.68, -1.52, 0],
    [-0.10, -3.43, 0], [-1.14, -2.66, 0], [-2.92, -2.51, 0], [-2.14, -1.62, 0],
    [-3.33, -0.44, 0], [-1.05, -3.85, 0], [0.38, 0.95, 0], [-0.05, -1.95, 0],
    [-3.20, -0.22, 0], [-2.26, 0.01, 0], [-1.41, -0.33, 0], [-1.20, -0.71, 0],
    [-1.69, 0.80, 0], [-1.52, -1.14, 0], [3.88, 0.65, 1], [0.73, 2.97, 1],
    [0.83, 3.94, 1], [1.59, 1.25, 1], [3.92, 3.48, 1], [3.87, 2.91, 1],
    [1.14, 3.91, 1], [1.73, 2.80, 1], [2.95, 1.84, 1], [2.61, 2.92, 1],
    [2.38, 0.90, 1], [2.30, 3.33, 1], [1.31, 1.85, 1], [1.56, 3.85, 1],
    [2.67, 2.41, 1], [1.23, 2.54, 1], [1.33, 2.03, 1], [1.36, 2.68, 1],
    [2.58, 1.79, 1], [2.40, 0.91, 1], [0.51, 2.44, 1], [2.17, 2.64, 1],
    [4.38, 2.94, 1], [1.09, 3.12, 1], [0.68, 1.54, 1], [1.93, 3.71, 1],
    [1.26, 1.17, 1], [1.90, 1.34, 1], [3.13, 0.92, 1], [0.85, 1.56, 1],
    [1.50, 3.93, 1], [2.95, 2.09, 1], [0.77, 2.84, 1], [1.00, 0.46, 1],
    [3.19, 2.32, 1], [2.92, 2.32, 1], [2.86, 1.35, 1], [0.97, 2.68, 1],
    [1.20, 1.31, 1], [1.54, 2.02, 1], [1.65, 0.63, 1], [1.36, -0.22, 1],
    [2.63, 0.40, 1], [0.90, 2.05, 1], [1.26, 3.54, 1], [0.71, 2.27, 1],
    [1.96, 0.83, 1], [2.52, 1.83, 1], [2.77, 2.82, 1], [4.16, 3.34, 1]
])

# Split data into features (X) and labels (y)
X = data[:, :2]
y = data[:, 2]

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)


# Perceptron class definition
class Perceptron():
    def __init__(self, num_features):
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.weights = np.random.rand(num_features) * 0.1  # Small random weights initialization
        self.bias = 0.0
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # Compute the linear output and apply step function
        linear = np.dot(x, self.weights) + self.bias
        predictions = np.where(linear > 0, 1, 0)
        return predictions
        
    def backward(self, x, y, predictions):
        # Calculate the error
        errors = y - predictions
        # Update weights and bias using the perceptron rule
        self.weights += self.learning_rate * np.dot(x.T, errors)
        self.bias += self.learning_rate * np.sum(errors)
        return errors
        
    def train(self, x, y, epochs, learning_rate=0.01):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        for e in range(epochs):
            # Calculate predictions for entire batch
            predictions = self.forward(x)
            # Update weights and bias after processing the entire batch
            self.backward(x, y, predictions)
                
    def evaluate(self, x, y):
        # Predict on the test data
        predictions = self.forward(x)
        # Calculate accuracy
        accuracy = np.mean(predictions == y)
        return accuracy

# Using the Perceptron class
perceptron = Perceptron(num_features=2)
perceptron.train(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, learning_rate=0.01)
accuracy = perceptron.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
accuracy_train = perceptron.evaluate(X_train, y_train)

# final result
accuracy, accuracy_train


I use, train_test_split before calling the function to test it quickly.
Here are some errors I spot in your code :

Batch Training: The training is now using the entire batch for weight updates.
Predictions Shape: The forward function has been adapted for batch input.
Learning Rate and Epochs: Adjust the number of epochs and learning rate for convergence.


This is not attempting to answer the question.

Yes it does, I said what I fixed in the code
